# How to prevent downloading using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have some video files few of which are not public. I want to access them through video player but I also need to prevent the direct download from the address bar.
 Also if a user pays for it they can download.
I tried in .htaccess file but still not solved.
I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(https?://)?yoursite.com
RewriteRule ^/?video_files - [L,F]
```

Comment: I don't know if using `.htaccess` is the right apprach for you. E.g. the `Referer` may or may not be set by the browser and can be easily manipulated. So even if your directives worked they would not really secure your content.

Comment: Are know any right approach for this?